# Which takes higher priority? Code or Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I've been messing with my UINavigationBar color in my iOS App written in Swift. When doing this, I know there are two ways to set the color - Either in Storyboard or in my Appdelegate code. Which of the two takes higher priority?

This applies to more than just UINavigationBars of course, so I thought it would be helpful to many newbies like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example you set a color in Interface Builder for an UINavigationBar and you also change the color in code for the same UINavigationBar, the color defined in code will be used.

Comment: You may want to explain the reason to the OP, that the storyboard's settings are applied when the object is created.  The code that changes the object's settings runs later, after the object has been created.